# Окраска ячейки по цвету соседней ячейки с соответствующим параметром

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Окраска ячейки по цвету соседней ячейки с соответствующим параметритом, возможно или нет? В общем написан скрипт, выводит данные в таблицу, формирование задано соответствующее значению, цветов 10+ возможно ли задать окраску другой ячейки соответствуя условия формирования текущий ячейки, при этом код нужно вписать в ячейку с условиями формирования.

Comment: параметритом = параметром (опечатка)

Comment: сейчас это выглядет так  *=TRANSPOSE(скрипт(A1))* и результат выводится в строку с кодом и окрашивается в цвет соответствующий условиям формирования

Comment: даже скорее всего это надо задать в условиях формирования, цвет=цвету соседней ячейки, но каковы формула не знаю =(

Answer (score 0):

Возможно.

Необходимо выбрать один из вариантов:

1. Использование условного форматирование
2. Программное форматирование

Оба варианта имеют свои недостатки:

1. На каждый цвет требуется свое правило. Если цветом 10+ то удовольствия мало.
2. При программном пересчете требуется постоянный запуск процедуры. Пользовательска функция не умеет форматировать ячейки.